# Store different datatype in same variable at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android development. I am facing difficulties to store different types of data in same variable.

Example :

I want to store integer value 1 or String value "one" or double value 1.0 to my variable at run time when user press button. but Here I don't see any datatype for this. If I declare variable as String the I can't store integer value. If I declare variable as integer the I can't store String value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is a static typed language. You cannot use the same variable to store different kinds of data. In short, what you want is not possible.

Comment: You can Use `String.valueOf(value)` ,here value = int,boolean,long etc. in your String variable. but here your int,long value store as a only string and while you get this value than again convert it to your specific datatype.

Comment: please think twice before downgrade mark. there is a answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your variable of type `Object`

```
Object val;

val = Integer.valueOf(12);
val = Double.parseDouble("12")
val = String.valueOf("12");
```

Later to read the content of `val` you will have to test is type, or example using `instanceof` and cast it into the desired type...

```
Object val = Integer.valueOf(12);
if(val instanceof Integer){
    Integer i = (Integer)val;
    int iVal = i.intValue(); 
}else if(val instanceof Double){
    //...
}else if (val instanceof String){
    //...
}//...
```